# Create membership package to download products

Tags: magento-1.9

i need to create for my e-commerce web site some membership package to download documents.

I want to give to my customer the possibility to buy a membership plan and after that they can download everything for free for example:

```
• bronze access - buy 1 hour full access
• silver access - buy 1 day full access
• gold access - buy 1 week full access
• platinum access - buy 1 month full access
• and so on
```

So if a customer buy the "silver access" he has a free access to full web site for 1 day, when the day expire he need to buy again the package or other package.

Can you give me some solution on how to do that if by programming or by extension?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

My idea on this:

Create a simple product to buy the membership.

After this, you can **automatically or manually** assign people who bought this membership into one or more **customer groups**.

For this customer group(s) you can set a **group price** on the downloadable products with "0" so they can access it for free. All others will see the standard price for the downloadable product.

Comment: Yes i understand i must test but i think is a good solution,...after that in which way i could control the time?...1 hour, 1 day, 1 week?...

Comment: I think you need to specify more in details what you are trying to do (maybe update your question).

Comment: thank you Anna for your suggestion i have updated the question